# Do not reset keyframe animation when class removed

Tags: javascript, css, keyframe

Is it possible to preserve the transition imposed by a keyframe animation? I would like to remove the class with the keyframe animation before it's finished and have the animation not reset.

example:

```
@keyframes right {
    100% {
        left: 500000px;
    }
}

.animate-right {
    animate: right 500s 1;
}
```

and the JS associated with clicking the element with the class is:

```
function(e) {
    var el = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
        el.className = el.className.replace('animate-right', '');
    }, 500);

    el.className += ' ' + animate-right;
}
```

Doing the above results in the animation being applied until the class it removed but with a reset back to the position before the animation has started. I have tried setting up start/stop points, but I would prefer not to do this as it is very brute force. example:

```
function(e) {
    var el = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
        el.style.left = el.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        el.className = el.className.replace('animate-right', '');
    }, 500);

    el.style.left = 0;
    el.className += ' ' + animate-right;
}
```

I have also tried applying `animation-play-state` at the end, but it still resets.

Comment: Only if you set the [`animation-play-state`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state) property via script at the same time as well I guess.

Comment: No you can't do that. Why are you removing the class before it's finished?

Comment: I'd like not to have to write many animations, but generic ones instead

Comment: _"I would like to remove the class with the keyframe animation before it's finished"_ How is `class` removed ? Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: I don't think a snippet/fiddle is necessary, it's pretty straightforward code. I will add some code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you remove the class? do not remove the class, just change the animationPlayState. a working example http://www.tutorialspark.com/css3/CSS3_Animation_Pause_Resume_Demo.php

if the class also does something else, then create two classes for it

Comment: and then just unpause in the event that the class already exists? this may work...let me try it.

Comment: if you want to animate it back, then change it back to `running`, anytime you want. but what do you mean by "class already exists"? i'm not sure i understand what exactly are you trying to do as you didn't tell when do you want to run it again

Comment: I mentioned the function above is associated with a click event the click event should toggle the animation. It was intended to do so by removing/adding a class, but it looks like it works to pause.

Comment: if you'd rather add and remove classes in javascript, you can always write another class which will have the `animation-play-state` property set to paused. like, when it's paused, your `el` will have two classes active: `animate-right` and `animation-paused`. the `animation-paused` can have a css declaration like `.animation-paused{ ... the paused css properties }`